# VBA Pivot Table, Row data fields aren't showing in the same column

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Good afternoon,

I'm having an issue with my VBA macro that creates a pivot table that i'm hoping someone can assist with, I've searched but can't find anything.

I've selected 3 data rows, but when I run the macro it puts them all in separate columns, rather than under the same column.

So just to explain it a little better, the 3 row headers that are selected are 'Product Barcode', 'Product number' 'Product description', and rather than putting them all in column A underneath each other, it puts each header in to a seperate column, so 'Product Barcode' is in column A, 'Product number' is in column B, and 'Product description' is in column C.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub TestingCategoryPivot3()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets("Data")
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")

'Define Data Range - i don't use this as i get a type mismatch error when i do
'LastRow = DSheet.Cells(DSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, DSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Data!R1C1:R20000C23")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(28, 1), TableName:="PivotTable7")

'Insert Row Fields
With PTable.PivotFields("Product Barcode")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Product Number")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Product Description")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 3
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With PTable.PivotFields("Category")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With PTable.PivotFields("Category")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Category")
.PivotItems("#VALUE!").Visible = False
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With

'Insert Pivot Filter
With PTable.PivotFields("Zone")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Product type")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 2
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Period")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 3
End With

'Format Pivot Table
PTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
PTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing the Report Layout feature. If you select Report Layout from the PivotTable Tools>Design Tab and select Show In Compact Form do you get what you're after?

Comment: Yep, this was exactly it. Thank you so much, i was pulling my hair out with this one!